# How to find missing id in the table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have column looks like below

```
SID101
SID102
SID103
SID105
SID107
```

In the above criteria i need to find missed SID numbers. SID104 and SID 106 are missed while ordering.

How can i find the missed id numbers.Could any one help me finding it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cularis : Thanks for formatting:-)

Comment: Is there a table with *all* the sid? Or does missing simply mean there is a gap?

Comment: I would suggest doing stuff like this in code, if it is about finding gaps.

Comment: Are all codes with 6 characters (`SIDxxx`) or it can be more (or less), like `SID2011` or `SIDE100` or `SID47` ?

Comment: All With 6 digit code. It does not have empty value. There is no record with missing SID  in the column

Answer (score 1):

If your table contains gaps with length more than 1 item, you can use this query:

```
declare @t table(s varchar(20))

insert @t values ('SID101'),('SID102'),('SID103'),('SID105'),('SID108');

with cte as
(
    select substring(t.s, 4, len(t.s)) [i]
    from @t t
)
select 'SID' + cast(m.number as varchar(20))
from master..spt_values m
left join cte c on c.i = m.number
where [Type] = 'P' 
    and m.number >= (select min(i) from cte) 
    and m.number <= (select max(i) from cte)
    and c.i is null
```

Output:

```
-----------------------
SID104
SID106
SID107
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult. With

```
SELECT COUNT(*),MAX(CAST(REPLACE(y.name,'SID','') AS INT)) AS col_max FROM
sys.objects x INNER JOIN sys.columns y ON x.object_id=y.object_id
WHERE x.name='<TABLE_NAME>'
```

you should know, how much columns are missing (i.e. `COUNT(*)` is 5 and `col_max` is 107)

When you have a table, which contains only one column with all possible IDs from 1 to max (i.e. 100,101,102,103,104,...,132) then you could do

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT CAST(REPLACE(y.name,'SID','') AS INT) AS col_id FROM
    sys.objects x INNER JOIN sys.columns y ON x.object_id=y.object_id
    WHERE x.name='<TABLE_NAME>'
) a
RIGHT JOIN <TABLE_IDS> b ON a.col_id=b.id
WHERE a.col_id IS NULL AND b.id<=(
    SELECT MAX(CAST(REPLACE(y.name,'SID','') AS INT)) AS col_max FROM
    sys.objects x INNER JOIN sys.columns y ON x.object_id=y.object_id
    WHERE x.name='<TABLE_NAME>'
)
```

**EDIT**: sorry, I've seen just now, that these values aren't column names, but values. My solution will find missing column names

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @i INT;
SET @i = 100;

CREATE TABLE #idsToCheck (checkId varchar(100));

WHILE (@i < 200)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #idsToCheck VALUES ('SID' + CONVERT(varchar(100), @i));
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END

SELECT * FROM #idsToCheck itc
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MainTable mt ON itc.checkId = mt.realId
    WHERE mt.realId = NULL

DROP TABLE #idsToCheck
```

... where `MainTable` is your table containing the `SID101`, `SID102`, etc. column values, and `MainTable.realId` is the column containing those IDs.  Modify the `@i` initial value and number in the while loop condition based on which SIDs you want to check from/to.

Answer (score 0):

   Declare @St int
            declare @end int

```
     set @st = CAST( (select RIGHT( max(data),4) from orderno)as int) 
     set @end = CAST( (select RIGHT( min(data),4) from orderno)as int)   

     create table #temp(data int)

    while(@St <= @end )
    begin
 insert into #temp values(@St)
 set @St = @St +1
   end

  select * from orderno 
  select * from #temp
 select data from #temp where data not in (select cast(RIGHT(data,4))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @t table(s varchar(20))

insert @t values ('SID101'),('SID102'),('SID103'),('SID105'),('SID107');

with cte as
(
    select substring(t.s, 4, len(t.s)) [i]
    from @t t
)

select 'SID' + cast(t1.i + 1 as varchar(20))
from cte t1
join cte t2 on t2.i > t1.i
    and not exists(
        select 1
        from cte c3
        where c3.i > t1.i and c3.i < t2.i
    )
where t2.i <> t1.i + 1
```

Output:

```
-----------------------
SID104
SID106
```

Comment: I didnt downvote, but i am guessing it is because you have 2solutions for the same question

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, I received downvote when I have posted only 1st solution. These solutions are for different cases, so I post 2 answers, instead of one.

Comment: Maybe also because this solution doesn't work for gaps where more than 1 element is missing. Try: insert @t values ('SID101'),('SID107')

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, Maybe, therefore I posted 2nd solution. I'm not telepathic, I don't know OP needs.